# Arguments not applicable with Generics in SpringFramework CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring

I have the following complete code:

```
public class Test
{
    private abstract class A {}
    private abstract class B<T extends A>
    {
        public abstract void addR(T r);
    }
    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a;
        B<? extends A> b;
        b.addR(a);
    }
}
```

This gives the following error:

The method addR(capture#1-of ? extends Test.A) in the type Test.B is not applicable for the arguments (Test.A)

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Don't you mean `interface AwsCostAllocationTagRepository extends AwsTagRepository<AllocationTag> {}`? Class cannot extend from itself...

Comment: Also, where's `AllocationTag` definition?

Comment: Of course you're correct. Those were unfortunate transcription errors. I've rectified those and added the missing @NoRepositoryBean, but the problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried implementing this without interfaces hierarchy? Have you tried using the list of AwsCostAllocationTags instead of the list of AwsTags?

Comment: Which version of Spring-Data are you using?

Comment: I'm using spring-boot-starter-* 1.2.5.RELEASE and eventually the dependencies get resolved with spring-data-commons 1.9.2.RELEASE, spring-data-jpa 1.7.2.RELEASE.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to abstract things is because I have AwsBillingDetailedLineitemWithResourceAndTagsTag which is also derived from AwsTags. The AwsRecord and AwsFile classes generate similar errors with their subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you're passing the wrong type of object to the `save` method.

But what should be it's type? The `CrudRepository` class is parameterized on `T`, which means the save method is of type `save(T entity)`.

What is `T` in this case?

Since you have this `interface AwsCostAllocationTagRepository extends AwsTagRepository<AllocationTag>` and this `interface AwsTagRepository<T extends Tag> extends CrudRepository<T, Long>`, then `T` is `AllocationTag`.

Thus, the signature of the `save` method is `save(AllocationTag entity)`.

You are calling this method with an object of type `List<AwsTag>`.

Type mismatch error!

Comment: I edited too much. Here's the full message: 
The method addAwsRecord(capture#68-of ? extends AwsRecord) in the type AwsFile<capture#68-of ? extends AwsRecord> is not applicable for the arguments (AwsRecord)

Comment: And actually, there are 2 methods in CrudRepository. There's "<S extends T> S save(S entity);" and there's "<S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);". The latter one should be the one being used. But even if I do the iteration myself and pass AwsTag rather than List<AwsTag> it fails the same way.

Comment: I've replaced the code with a more concise and complete example. I've also supplied the new error code which is equivalent to the original.

Comment: Same problem, types don't match. The type `A` is not the same as type `capture#1`. To put it *very* simply, `capture#1` is a bogus type that will never match anything. Thus, the type `B<? extends A>` is read-only. This is called *covariance*. We know that whatever is in `B` is an instance of `A`, so we can safely take things out. But since we don't know the actual type, it isn't safe to put anything in. `List<Double>` and `List<Integer>` are both `List<? extends Number>`, but if `List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>()`, We want `x.get(0).intValue()`, but not `x.add(1.5)`.

Comment: The alternative is `B<? super A>`, which is write-only. This is *contravariance*. We know that whatever is in `B`, it is a supertype of `A`, so we can safely add objects of type `A`. So if `List<? super Integer> x = new ArrayList<Number>()` or `List<? super Integer> x = new ArrayList<Object>()`, we want to be able to do `x.add(1)`. A list of numbers and a list of objects can both hold integers. But that's all we know, so we can't make any assumptions about what `x.get(0)` would return. Thus `B<? super A>` would be write-only.